# Spotify refresh token in Python 3

Tags: python, spotify, webapi

I am attempting to get a refresh token and use it to request a new access token when the temporary access token expires.
Spotify's documentation states the response body should contain the following json data:

```
{
   "access_token": "NgCXRK...MzYjw",
   "token_type": "Bearer",
   "scope": "user-read-private user-read-email",
   "expires_in": 3600,
   "refresh_token": "NgAagA...Um_SHo"
}
```

However, using my code below only provides the following:

```
{
  "access_token": "xxxx....",
  "token_type": "Bearer",
  "expires_in": 3600
}
```

I am using the following function to request an access token:

```
def get_access_token(client_id, client_secret):   # getting access token from spotify using client ID
    #  Encoding Client ID and Client Secret in Base64
    token_url = "https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token"
    client_creds = f"{client_id}:{client_secret}"
    client_creds_b64 = base64.b64encode(client_creds.encode())
    token_data = {
        "grant_type":  "client_credentials"
    }
    token_headers = {
        'Authorization': f"Basic {client_creds_b64.decode()}"
    }
    r = requests.post(token_url, data=token_data, headers=token_headers)
    valid_request = r.status_code in range(200, 299)
    token_response_data = r.json()
    # pretty print response body
    print(json.dumps(token_response_data, indent=2))    # response 200 -> successful attempt
    if valid_request:
        access_token = token_response_data['access_token']  
    return access_token
```

I am unsure why the scope and refresh token are missing from the response body. How can I alter this function to include these?

Thanks in advance for your time!

Spotify documentation: https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization/code-flow/

Answer (score 0):

Altering the token data fixes this:

```
    token_data = {
        "grant_type": "authorization_code",
        "code": "xxxx....",
        "redirect_uri": "your redirect uri from Spotify for devs"
     }
```

You need to set up a redirect uri on Spotify for devs, then encode it to use it as a parameter.

To get the 'code' parameter fill-out this URL with your data and you will be redirected to your redirect uri.
`https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?client_id=YOUR CLIENT ID&response_type=code&redirect_uri=YOUR ENCODED REDIRECT URI&scope=playlist-modify-public%20playlist-modify-private`

The code will then be in the search bar to copy/paste. It should look something like this:

`https://your redirectURI?code=xxx.....`

Here is a good video guide for reference:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-FsFT6OwE1A&ab_channel=EuanMorgan